# Start two scripts that run indefinitely in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm a webdev and I am using JSX compiler and SASS preprocessor to compile my `.jsx` and `.scss` files. When I start working, I launch these two separate commands:

```
jsx -x jsx jsx js --watch --no-cache-dir
sass stylesheets/scss/app.scss:stylesheets/css/app.css --watch
```

As you can see, both have a `--watch` flag, meaning they will keep tracking their respective files until they are killed. I want to be able to use a shell script, that launches both of these scripts at once. So far I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting JSX Compiler..."
jsx -x jsx jsx js --watch --no-cache-dir
echo "Starting SASS Preprocessor"
sass stylesheets/scss/app.scss:stylesheets/css/app.css --watch
```

but this only executes the first program `jsx` and not `sass` because jsx is running. How can I launch both of these "watch" type programs via a shellscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilies here do achive your goal.

First, you can start the first command in the background by simply adding an ampersand "&" at the end of the commandline:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "Starting JSX Compiler..."
jsx -x jsx jsx js --watch --no-cache-dir &
echo "Starting SASS Preprocessor" 
sass stylesheets/scss/app.scss:stylesheets/css/app.css --watch &
```

By doing this, you can work on using the same terminal, maybe output to sdtout and stderr will get displayed in the terminal, which sometimes can be a bit confusing. But the processes will run in background until you close the terminal.

If that is not enough and you want the processes to run even if the terminal is closed, you need the `nohup` command additionally here:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "Starting JSX Compiler..."
nohup jsx -x jsx jsx js --watch --no-cache-dir &
echo "Starting SASS Preprocessor" 
nohup sass stylesheets/scss/app.scss:stylesheets/css/app.css --watch &
```

This will start your processes in background as well, you're still using the ampersands at the end of the commands, but it will tell your processes additionally to ignore the HUP-Signal. That way the processes will run till the program terminates, the process gets killed or the system shuts down.